# 'str' object is not callable Am I wrong to assign User to method wrong?

Tags: python, django

I wanna print out  composite_id in views.py.
I wrote in response method like

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User
def response(request):
        user = User()
        composite_id = user.composite(User)
        print(composite_id)

    return render(request, 'response.html')
```

in models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
import random

class User(models.Model):
    uu_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    random_id = random.randint(1000,9999)

    @property
    def composite(self):
        return ''.join([str(self.uu_id), '_', str(self.regist_date), '_', str(self.random_id)])
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens because I do not think I assign string somewhere.
But I think ,maybe am I wrong to assign User to method wrong?
But I think argument of views.py's composite method should be User bacause  models.py's self = User.How should I fix this?What should I write it?
Traceback is

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\app\app\views.py" in response
  27.         composite_id = user.composite(User)

Exception Type: TypeError at /app/response
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

I rewrote by comment,now I wrote in views.py

```
def response(request):
    user = User
    composite_id = user.composite
    print(composite_id)
```

so,print(composite_id) is .I wanna show composite_id as string not object,so what method should I add to do it?

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Show us the exact line on which the error occurred and show us the content of that line

Comment: @SandeepLade I added traceback

Comment: @RayToal I added traceback

Comment: Ah, you made `composite` a property, so `user.composite` is a string. You then wrote `user.composite(User)` which means you were treating the string `user.composite` as a function by trying to pass `User` to it.

Comment: @RayToal thx ur comment!!I achieved my goal little bit,but I added my question to do my ideal thing.If you know something please teach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your last update to the question where you rewrote your view code, `user = User` simply associates the variable named `user` with the class `User`. It does not create an instance of it.

```
>>> user = User
>>> print(user.composite)
<property object at 0x7f167878c7c8>
```

You need to create an instance of class `User` and then access its `composite` property:

```
>>> user = User()
>>> print(user.composite)
a694ad29-1955-4ffa-84af-3c79c309421c_None_1195
```

I think it would be a good idea for you to read a tutorial or two about Python classes as you seem a little confused by them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1) # here your existin user id
print(user.composite)
```